# Converting a specific "If statement" from PHP to ASP

Tags: php, asp.net

This will probably be a simple question for some.  I am just delving into the asp.net world.  I have inherited a php script that I need to convert to asp.net.  I know that there are converters out there but I can't use them. The gist of my issue is that I have numerous "if" statement that follow the same PHP format.

PHP format is:

```
if ($_GET['id'] == "Word") {
   $location = "http://www.word.com" ;
}
```

How should this look in asp.net?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: You requested that this be converted to ASP.NET, but you didn't specify whether the language you're using is C# or VB.NET. ASP.NET is just a framework, not a language. Also, you didn't make any attempt to convert it yourself.

Comment: I have googled and searched through the database here.  Like I said.. I am new at this and have not been to any training. Just looking for pointers not looking to have someone do my work for me.

Comment: Also.. I am using vb.net.

Comment: You should tag your question with the appropriate language.

Answer (score 0):

If statement is comparing querystring - id with "word". `$_GET` stands for get request, that is `Request.QueryString` in asp.net ( i mean C# or vb.net). So asp.net translation will be like following.

**C#.net version**

```
if(Request.QueryString["id"]!= null && Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() == "Word")
{
    // write code for assigning location variable
}
```

**VB.net version**

```
If Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Request.QueryString("id") = "Word" Then
    ' write code for assigning location variable
End If
```

I would suggest do a null check of `Request.Querystring` before comparison.

Comment: does the rest remain the same? and forgive my ignorance but how do I do the null check and where does it go in the code?

Comment: @navycubfan Do you know what a null check is? It's checking that a value is not null before you access it. Therefore, you'd place the null check before accessing the value.